# Grab Table Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in HTML that holds names, addresses and phone numbers.

In each row for that table, there is a link you can select that opens up a popover. When a popover is selected, I would like to store the name for that specific row. The class associated with a name is

```
<td class="du-orl-1"> Daniel </td>
```

I am trying to store that name in a class via Javascript but this just seems to store the whole array of data rather than the specific element:

```
var objectId = $(".du-orl-1").html($(this).html());
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does "this" means in your context?

Comment: It sounds like your interaction event is on the <tr> or <table> element and not on the <td> element. But, like Foca suggests, providing what the `this` in your code is would be helpful, as you want the `this` to be the <td> in question.

Comment: +1 for clear explanation and current markup and jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following jQuery should be helpful:

```
var objectId = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.du-orl-1').text();
```

Should give you the name on the row where the link was clicked.

**Note**: *this* refers to the `anchor` element (link) that was clicked; therefore this piece of code should be inside the `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectId = $("#myTable .du-orl-1").text();
```

or this :

```
var objectId = $("#myTable").find(".du-orl-1").text();
```

First try to add `id` of your table, and next to it your `td class`

Comment: This returns all names in my table rather than the one selected.